# Writing DataTable/DataSet to Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, dataset

I'm looping through a database and querying by month then inserting this data into a `DataTable` for each month of the users specified year. I'd like to insert this `DataTable` into a new sheet of an Excel Workbook. Thus I'd end up with 12 sheets in my single Excel workbook.

So I have a couple questions stemming from this.

> Would it be better to have a DataSet containing my 12 DataTables (one for each month)? And then is there a quick and easy way of creating an Excel spreadsheet from my DataSet and being that there are 12 DataTables in that set it would create a separate sheet for each DataTable?

And then the other question being

> Is it more simple or easier to just create 12 different DataTables and create a workbook and a separate sheet for each DataTable in the workbook and fill that sheet from the DataTable one by one?

Comment: can you show some code of what you are doing currently.. also if this information is being used for reporting for example.. why don't you just export the data to PDF using the ITextSharp dll it's free ... can you give a visual example of what your data looks like..? show your code on how your are querying and returning datatable from your database

Comment: That first sentence sounds like the kind of thing that should be done with a single query/databind, no loops involved.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn do a single query encompassing the entire year and then let the code sort it out by month thereby running less queries on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/753207/Export-DataSet-into-Excel-using-Csharp-Excel-Inter) is pretty much exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all data into one DataTable, query for distinct months then loop through the rows of data, create the sheet and insert data. The example below does this using mocked data placed into a DataTable. There are two sql statements, one for creating sheets and one for inserting data. When finished, for this example there will be a sheet for three months, not 12 unless there were at least one record per month or more. If you had to come back and insert more rows then additional logic would be needed which has not be asked for but we would need to first see if the sheet exists which can be done a simply attempting to create an existing sheet would throw an exception. I kepted this example very simple.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo1_CS
{
    public class MonthDemo
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Let's look at this as data coming back from a database table
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public DataTable Table()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
            {
                ColumnName = "ID",
                DataType = typeof(int),
                AutoIncrement = true
            });
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
            {
                ColumnName = "Month",
                DataType = typeof(string)
            });
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
            {
                ColumnName = "Name",
                DataType = typeof(string)
            });

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "January", "Karen Payne" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "January", "Bill Smith" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "March", "George Jones" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "April", "Frank White" });

            return dt;

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get a list of distinct month names
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<string> MonthNames()
        {
            return Table()
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Month"))
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
        }
        public void Work()
        {
            // SQL responsible for creating sheets
            string createCommandText =
                        @"
                            CREATE TABLE {0}
                            (
                                ID INT,
                                Name CHAR(255)
                            )";

            // SQL responsible for inserting rows of data
            string insertCommandText = @"
                        INSERT INTO {0}
                        (
                            ID,
                            Name
                        )
                        VALUES
                        (
                            @ID,
                            @Name
                        )
                    ";

            // assumes this file exists
            string FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "DemoMonths.xlsx");

            List<DataRow> result;

            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = "TODO"})
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { Connection = cn })
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter() { ParameterName = "@ID", DbType = DbType.Int32 });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter() { ParameterName = "@MonthName", DbType = DbType.String });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter() { ParameterName = "@Name", DbType = DbType.String });

                    // assume the file will open else use a try-catch
                    cn.Open();

                    // Iterate months, get rows and insert rows into proper sheet
                    foreach (string monthName in MonthNames())
                    {
                        result = Table().AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("Month") == monthName).ToList();
                        if (result.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow row in result)
                            {
                                // assumes sheet does not exists, create it
                                cmd.CommandText = string.Format(createCommandText, monthName);

                                try
                                {
                                    // test if create sheet worked
                                    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                                    {

                                        // load values into command object parameters
                                        cmd.CommandText = string.Format(insertCommandText, monthName);
                                        cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = row.Field<int>("ID");
                                        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = row.Field<string>("Name");

                                        // insert row data
                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    // simply an example, best to say write to a log file
                                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to create or insert: {0}", ex.Message);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```